# Hovering an SVG element in Selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, selenium-webdriver

as the title states I am trying to get selenium to hover on certain elements within my SVG graph. Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="chart-impl-year" class="chart-impl" style="display: block;">
  <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; opacity: 1;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="858" height="342">
      <desc>Created with Raphaël</desc>
      <defs>
      <path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" d="M55.5,111.5L55.5,315.5L80.5,315.5L80.5,111.5Z" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
      <path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" d="M120.5,161.5L120.5,315.5L145.5,315.5L145.5,161.5Z" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
      <path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" d="M186.5,315.5L186.5,315.5L211.5,315.5L211.5,315.5Z" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
      <path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" d="M252.5,315.5L252.5,315.5L277.5,315.5L277.5,315.5Z" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
      <path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" d="M317.5,315.5L317.5,315.5L342.5,315.5L342.5,315.5Z" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
      <path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" d="M383.5,315.5L383.5,315.5L408.5,315.5L408.5,315.5Z" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
      <path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" d="M449.5,315.5L449.5,315.5L474.5,315.5L474.5,315.5Z" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
      <path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" d="M514.5,315.5L514.5,315.5L539.5,315.5L539.5,315.5Z" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
      <path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" d="M580.5,315.5L580.5,315.5L605.5,315.5L605.5,315.5Z" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
      <path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" d="M646.5,315.5L646.5,315.5L671.5,315.5L671.5,315.5Z" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
      <path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" d="M711.5,315.5L711.5,315.5L736.5,315.5L736.5,315.5Z" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
      <path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" d="M777.5,315.5L777.5,315.5L802.5,315.5L802.5,315.5Z" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
      <path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" d="M55.5,91.5L55.5,111.5L80.5,111.5L80.5,91.5Z" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
      <path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" d="M120.5,146.5L120.5,161.5L145.5,161.5L145.5,146.5Z" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
      <circle cx="68.5" cy="153.5" r="10" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
      <circle cx="134.5" cy="118.5" r="10" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
      <circle cx="199.5" cy="113.5" r="10" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
      <circle cx="265.5" cy="101.5" r="10" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
    </svg>
  </div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="858" height="342">
  <div class="label-axis-top label-axis-left" style="left: 0.5px; top: -3.5px;">320 Hours</div>
  <div class="label-axis-top label-axis-right" style="right: -0.5px; top: -3.5px;">120° F</div>
</div>
```

My test

```
Given(/^I place cursor on the temperature pointer for inside temp on the line graph$/) do
 # page.find_element(:xpath,".//*[@id='chart-impl-year']/div[1]/svg/circle[1]").hover
 # find(:xpath, ".//*[@id='chart-impl-year']/div[1]/local-name()='svg'/circle[1]").hover
 # find(:xpath, ".//*[@cx ='68.5']").hover
end
```

I've left the ways I've tried it commented out in the test so you can see the different xpath tries.  I get either unable to find xpath, or invalid selector

Answer (score 0):

Hi came across something similar with SVG, i was able to navigate through and hover elements mainly using CSS Selectors.

It was something to do with Dragging elements and dropping in SVG Circle, the child position varies based on screen size that's what i've also noticed.
Hope this helps..

```
    WebElement dragHandler = Context.instanceDriver.findElement
    (By.cssSelector("#canvas svg :nth-last-child(41)"));

    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

    actions.clickAndHold(some element).moveToElement(dragHandler)
     .release(dragHandler).build().perform();
```